# Is there an easy way to signal changes to data happening in child component?

Tags: c#, blazor

Let's say I have a collection of data in my page loaded via OnInitializedAsync(). The data is shown graphically in a table but later on also in more detail in another table further down on the page.
Since the rows in the detailed table has a lot of controls and logic I decided to make a component for the row e.g. `<RowData Data="@rowdata" />` and bound each row data.

The problem is that if the data gets changed in my child controller (RowData) it won't reflect in my first table in the "parent" component where the same data is also listed.

Is there an easy way to signal change or should I avoid making child components?

I have sovled it by making an EventCallback in my child component and updating via callback in my parent component. But I have the feeling I'm missing something.

Comment: I just read up on two way binding between components (https://chrissainty.com/a-detailed-look-at-data-binding-in-blazor/). I guees I did somewhat right.

Comment: I guees I was hoping for some easier 2-way binding with cascading update magic of some kind. Blazor is alot of magic in itself though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following sample shows how to perform two-way data-binding between a parent 
component and its child component. In each of these two component is a text box controls. When you type text in the parent component's text box, the text in the child component's text box changes to reflect the changes made in the parent, 
and vice versa...

### ChildComponent.razor

```
    <div style="border:solid 1px red">
        <h2>Child Component</h2>
         <input type="text" @bind="Text" @bind:event="oninput" />
    </div>

@code {
    private string text { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set
        {
            if (text != value) {
                text = value;
                if (TextChanged.HasDelegate)
                {
                    TextChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> TextChanged { get; set; }
}
```

### ParentComponent.razor

```
@page "/ParentComponent"

<h1>Parent Component</h1>

<input type="text" @bind="Text" @bind:event="oninput" />
<p></p>

<ChildComponent @bind-Text="Text" />


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Text { get; set; } = "Hello Blazor";
}
```

> I have sovled it by making an EventHandler in my child component and updating via callback. But I have the feeling I'm missing something

What you've been missing is the existence of the EventCallback 'delegate' used in this sample to call the parent component and pass it the value entered in the child component. This is how we define the 'delegate'

```
 [Parameter]
 public EventCallback<string> TextChanged { get; set; }
```

And this is how we invoke it, when the value of the Text property changes:

```
TextChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
```

What delegate did you use ? Note that the EventCallback's target is not the child component, but the parent component...

Good luck... If something is not clear, don't hesitate to ask...

Comment: I did have an EventCallback and as I said, I did solve it but was maybe looking for a simpler solution but I guess this is how you do it. I will mark your answer as a solution though.

Comment: I guees I was hoping for some easier 2-way binding with cascading update magic of some kind. Blazor is alot of magic in itself though :)

Comment: This method is most appropriate when parent-child components are involved. But you may create a state service if you have to maintain states when more components are involved, nested in each others, etc. There are also libraries dedicated to state management.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a root component with N levels of nested components (children within children ad-nauseam) then you can use a cascading value. Try something like this

```
public class MyState
{
  public List<MyObject> Objects { get; set; }
  public Action OnModified { get; }

  public MyState(List<MyObject> objects, Action onModified)
  {
    Objects = objects;
    OnModified = onModified;
  }
}
```

In your parent component

```
MyState State;

protected override OnInitialized()
{
  State = new MyState(your objects, () => InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged));
}
```

In your parent markup

```
<CascadingValue Value=State>
  All your child content here
</CascadingValue>
```

In your various child components that need access

```
[CascadingParameter]
public MyState State { get; set; }

protected void SomeEditWasMade()
{
  State.Objects[23].Name = "Bob";
  State.OnModified();
}
```

That should call the `() => InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` in the parent, and then that component and every component that consumes the `MyState` cascading value will get rerendered.

Or you could use something like [Fluxor](https://github.com/mrpmorris/Fluxor/tree/master/Docs) :)